# Vlookup to Make a list?

Tags: google-sheets-api

This site has been super helpful, thank you to everyone who has answered my questions. Here is the next one I am working on. Not sure if I should use `vlookup`, `hlookup`, a combination of both or something else.

So I have a list of teams with lineups

| Team | Player |
| --- | --- |
| A | Sam |
| A | Chris |
| A | Tom |
| A | Scott |
| B | Mark |
| B | Dan |
| B | Greg |
| B | Ben |
| C | Sara |
| C | Beth |
| C | Luara |
| C | Britt |

On a separate page I am trying to fill in a line up "IF" a team is selected.
For reference this is the current formula I have been trying:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Team LineUps'!$B:$B,Match(0,COUNTIF($C$16,IF('Team LineUps'!$A:$A=$C$16,'Team LineUps'!$B:$B,$C$16)),0)),"")
```

This will get me The first player on the list for a team. If I change the `0` to a `1` it will get me the last player on the team. How can I/ Can I? get the entire list 1-4? Or is it only a "true" OR "False"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Use a `QUERY`.*

#### Formula:

```
=QUERY('Team LineUps'!A2:B13, "SELECT B WHERE A='"&B4&"'")
```

#### Example Usage:

[image]

Comment: Fluff in posts [is discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). Please don't revert edits that remove it - and please don't add it to your posts in the first place

Comment: Systematically going through answers of a single user to remove a harmless closing line isn't productive to the site either - It doesn't actually _achieve_ anything. At best It's an excuse to make mass edits in order to earn badges, but in actuality only helps to garner the awful, unfreiendly reputation that Stackoverflow already has. It's a pity. @Zoe.